# php.ini configuration: display all errors and warnings but only log errors

Tags: php, configuration

As the title suggests, I would like PHP to display all errors and warnings (E_ALL) but I would like to only log the errors (E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT) is that possible?

Here is how I have my php.ini configured:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
log_errors = On
```

Running PHP 8.1.1

Thanks!

Comment: What happens currently? `display_errors` should be `off` i would think

Comment: No, it's not because displaying errors is dependent on the concept of first reporting them from the error handler. Once the error handler has reported an error of an allowable type (in your case __any__ error) then displaying it is simply a binary case of yes or no (in your case yes).